# Keras' clear_session() not working in Google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I run a keras model for several times in Google colab. Due to the nature of tensorflow there is a new model created each time of the program run, which leads to exhausted memory after some runs. I found that `clear_session()` of keras should help at the problem, but it doesn't seem to work. I created an MWE for Google colab below.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

X = np.zeros([10, 10000])
y = np.zeros([10, 10000])

########
m = Sequential([Dense(10000, input_shape=(10000,)), Dense(10000), Dense(10000), Dense(10000)])
m.compile(loss='mse')
m.summary()

m.fit(X,y)
K.clear_session()
```

After running the part below `########` for three times, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-7ae5ab890fc2> in <module>
      3 m.summary()
      4 
----> 5 m.fit(X,y)
      6 K.clear_session()

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'RMSprop/RMSprop/update_2/mul_2' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 381, in dispatch_queue
      yield self.process_one()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 346, in wrapper
      runner = Runner(result, future, yielded)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1080, in __init__
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
      raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-3-7ae5ab890fc2>", line 5, in <module>
      m.fit(X,y)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 893, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 539, in minimize
      return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 682, in apply_gradients
      name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 724, in _distributed_apply
      var, apply_grad_to_update_var, args=(grad,), group=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 706, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      update_op = self._resource_apply_dense(grad, var, **apply_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/rmsprop.py", line 216, in _resource_apply_dense
      var_t = var - coefficients["lr_t"] * grad / (
Node: 'RMSprop/RMSprop/update_2/mul_2'
failed to allocate memory
     [[{{node RMSprop/RMSprop/update_2/mul_2}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_2465]
```

I want to play around with slightly different data on the same model, so I run a similar part several times. I can simply restart the notebook after the error, but it takes some time to load the data, so is there an option how I can really clear an old model? Thanks for help.

Comment: The error message is not complete, and do not post errors as images, only as text.

Comment: Set your k.clear_session() before mode.fit(x,y) and this error occurs because your all available ram is exhausted... First make the model and then before fitting the model to the training data do keras.backend.clear_session(). I hope this error will be gone.

Comment: Unfortunately, executing K.clear_session() before m.fit(x,y) didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your model has 400 million parameters, it is larger than most pretrained models, like VGG, maybe it is actually too big for your hardware and clear session has nothing to do with this problem. For comparison, holding weights/gradients of this model each takes 1.6GB of memory.

Comment: That big network was created to reproduce the error faster, the original network I use is much smaller, thus needs much more runs of model creation and fitting until the memory gets, but the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

Please **restart the runtime** and try again as I tried replicating the above code and it's working fine.

You can check the output mentioned below for the same code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

X = np.zeros([10, 10000])
y = np.zeros([10, 10000])

########
m = Sequential([Dense(10000, input_shape=(10000,)), Dense(10000), Dense(10000), Dense(10000)])
m.compile(loss='mse')
m.summary()

m.fit(X,y, epochs=2)
K.clear_session()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 10000)             100010000 
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 10000)             100010000 
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10000)             100010000 
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 10000)             100010000 
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 400,040,000
Trainable params: 400,040,000
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 10s 10s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: Hi, yes it is correct that the basic execution is running. But if you repeat the part below the ```########``` for three times, then the execution fails.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a garbage collector for clear memory at the end of the loop:
use it after `K.clear_session()`

```
import gc

for _ in ():
    ...
    model = MyOwnModel()
    model.compile(...)
    model.fit(...)
    
    K.clear_session()
    gc.collect()
```

if it doesn't work change the version of TensorFlow with this code in Colab, before that cell:
for me, it does work after changing the version of TensorFlow

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.10.0
```